# Monitor snmp traps sent from python

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I use *pysnmp* to send snmp traps from my python program to a destination windows machine.

I want to test that traps are really sent. How can I test it easily? Is there some sort of a free snmp manager software I should install on the destination windows machine?

How is the setup process? I'm guessing I should, at some point, load my MIB file in the snmp manager software. Are there other things to consider?

I tried to use "PowerSNMP" but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try Net-SNMP's [snmptrapd](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:Configuring_snmptrapd#Debugging_SNMP_Applications_and_Agents) or [script like this](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/manager/ntfrcv/transport-tweaks.html#serving-multiple-network-interfaces) or just snoop with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to see what's going out to the network.

Alternatively, you can enable pysnmp debugging to see what's going inside your script and what it eventually sends to the network.

```
from pysnmp import debug

debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all'))
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering but I rather not using wireshark or debugging pysnmp.. Can't I just install snmp manager/monitoring program that I can load my MIB file into and get the alerts?